# why we need to copy the instance variable

Tags: python, oop

I am new in OOP and I am trying to understand why it wouldn't work if we wouldn't copy the sound.

```
class Pet():

    sounds = ['Mrrp']
    def __init__(self, name = "Kitty"):
        self.name = name
    # copy the class attribute, so that when we make changes to it, we won't affect the other Pets in the class
        self.sounds = self.sounds[:]

   def teach(self, word):
        self.sounds.append(word)
```

Comment: have you tried anything to see why it doesn't work unless you copy it?

Comment: Show us what you tried. Instantiate a dog and a frog, and alter their sounds.

Comment: for example, if I add a new sound for Pet A, the Pet B also get the sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't define `sounds` as a class variable in the first place; having a class variable and an instance variable that share the same name is just begging for confusion.  Just initialize it to its default in your `__init__`:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name = "Kitty"):
        self.name = name
        self.sounds = ['Mrrp']
```

The comment in your original code explains the purpose of that line pretty well; if you have a class variable `sounds`, and you set your instance variable to the same value as the class variable, anything you do to *mutate* that value is shared across the entire class.  The slice operator `[:]` returns a copy of the list, instead of the original list, so that `self.sounds` and `Pet.sounds` are two different lists.  (At the time you run the line `self.sounds = self.sounds[:]`, the `self.sounds` on the right is actually the class variable `Pet.sounds`, but `Pet.sounds` is "shadowed" within `self` as soon as you assign a value to `self.sounds`.)

To avoid this type of confusion (and it is easy to get confused with code like this, even if you're experienced): if you want a value to be shared across a class, make it a class variable; if you want it to be unique to each instance, make it an instance variable.  Don't make it one and then the other.